# Canvas drawing doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

In an application i'm working on it should be possible to open several div boxes and draw on each of them (like MS paint light).

I have succeeded open one box and draw on it but when I changed from canvas "id" to canvas "class" (to be able to open several boxes and paint on each of them) it stopped working. Now when I try to paint, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
var color = "red";
var shape = "square";
var size = 10;

var theWindow = $('.window').last();
var bottomWindow = $('.windowBottom').last();

var letsdraw = false;
var theCanvas = $('.paint').last();

var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
theCanvas.width  = 430;
theCanvas.height = 317;

var canvasOffset = $(theCanvas).offset();

$(theCanvas).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (letsdraw === true) {
        ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});

$(theCanvas).mousedown(function(e) {
    letsdraw = true;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = size;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
});

$(window).mouseup(function() {
    letsdraw = false;
});
```

Comment: actually, most of the html is created dynamically through DOM and it is much code. The div box i'm talking about is a div (class: window) and inside a topdiv and a bottomdiv. The canvas is put in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is you are still treating it as one canvas.

```
$('.paint').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (letsdraw === true) {
        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
        var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
        ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
```

So I removed `theCanvas` and using `this` to reference the canvas. Click the demo link to see it in action:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3HAq/6)

---

Some more edits using the [**data**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attr:

```
// using data attr to store lets draw per canvas
$(window).mouseup(function() {
    $('.paint').each(function () {
       $(this).data('letsdraw', false); 
    });
});

$('.paint').mousemove(function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('letsdraw') === true) {
        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
        var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
        ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
```

---

Changing the height and width:

```
$('.paint').each(function () {
    this.width = 430;
    this.height = 20
})
```

I only do this once, because changing the height/width of a canvas actually erases all drawing.

Comment: Great, thanks! One thing though... How do I change width and height of each canvas? Setting width and height like this: theCanvas.width = 430 doesn't work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to do that part, oops. I updated for that. No problem, glad to help